# Ubuntu low disk space on Filesystem root. How to resize root or delete files?

Tags: ubuntu, elementaryos

When I first installed Ubuntu (actually ElementaryOS) I didn't think that it would take up that much space, so I made the OS partition 15GB and `/home` 100GB. `sda5` and `sda6` are my Linux partitions.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x1b518505

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      823295      410624    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          823296   410943487   205060096    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       410943488   738621439   163838976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       738623486   976771071   119073793    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       738623488   767918079    14647296   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       767920128   976771071   104425472   83  Linux
```

[image]

The thing is, I don't actually have anything new installed on the OS now compared to when it was fresh. Just a browser and sublime text. Over time, installing system updates, the size just keeps on going up and up.

[image]

`/usr/src` has 2.2 GB of folders named `linux-headers-X.XX.X-XX`

`/lib/modules` has 3.9 GB of `X.XX.X-XX-generic` folders

Advice on what to do would be appreciated.

- If I choose to increase the size of the 15GB partition, how do I do it?
- What are `/usr/src` and `/lib/modules` and how do I delete them safely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there is a connection between the various aspects to your question.

- `/usr/src` is a location for source code for installed packages.
- `/lib/modules` is a location for kernel modules.
- `linux-headers-X.XX.X-XX` are the header files for your installed
  kernel(s). Header files are used when you wish to [compile a kernel
  module for your specific kernel](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x49.html). Many common pieces of software
  compile kernel modules, like [Virtualbox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox), lm-sensors, etc. see
  [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27042/what-does-a-kernel-source-tree-contain-is-this-related-to-linux-kernel-headers) for some more detailed discussion of exactly how they
  manifest. I always [install the kernel headers](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-kernel-headers-package/) and the
  `build-essential` package when setting up a new desktop, as I usually end
  up needing it at some point (I don't for servers though, compilers can be a security risk).

So, this all leads me to believe that you have more than one kernel installed, which is a pretty common problem. Its not a bad idea to keep one version back, especially right after an upgrade, but they are large, and can pile up.

Even if you have only one Kernel, You do not need the headers except when installing something that requires compilation against the kernel, so you can always uninstall the packages from Synaptic or software center.

if you have multiple old kernels still installed, you can usually remove them with `sudo apt-get autoremove` or review the [options here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu#) for your system. In addition to clearing the kernels, and the header source files, this will also remove the old kernel's modules, stored in `/lib/modules`

15GB is usually more than sufficient for a root partition, and resizing partitions is a tricky proposition, but it is definitely possible. I strongly recommend you consult [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition) to review your situation, and plan the operation. it will involve shrinking `/home`, [moving it to the right](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/MovingPartition), and finally extending the `/`.

Comment: I don't know why I would have so many versions of kernels installed. I'm not even 100% sure of what a kernel ***does***. I'm simply letting ElementaryOS' system updater do its thing. I've never, ever, re-used the stuff in `/lib/modules` and I also don't have multiple options in my boot menu - it's still the same singular ElementaryOS boot option. Should I just delete all the other folders except the two most recent ones that's in there? I've tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` already.

Comment: I removed all the `linux-header` and `linux-image` stuff expect for the most recent two using `Synaptic Package Manager`. Everything still seems to be working fine. It freed up 7GB of space so now my installation is back to around its original newly-installed size.

Comment: Excellent. The kernel is the very core of your OS. it loads and controls all the devices that the computer uses (cpu, ram, I\O, audio, video, network, etc) and coordinates their use in running higher level programs. You boot into a kernel (grub usually displays a list of them), and when loaded into memory, the kicks off the starting of services via some form of init system. The kernel image and the drivers loaded into it in memory **is** the booted system. everything else is just a program.